# Check if document already exists if not create one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im learning expressjs + mongo. I want to check after user logs in with passport through Steam if his data is already in database if not to create a record for him.

For this I created a static method in schema. Unfortunatelly i can't save from the inside of it.

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'create'

```
SteamAccountSchema.statics.checkAccount = function(identifier){
this.findOne({ 'identifier' : identifier }, function(err, account){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Checking account:" + account)
    if(account) {
        console.log("user already in db")
        return true
    } else {
        console.log("Creating new user account")
        this.create({
            name : 'username',
            identifier: identifier
        }, function(err){
            if(err) throw err;
            // if (err) return done(err);
            return false
        });
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cache the *this* object. I.e. in the code below *self* points to what you need:

```
SteamAccountSchema.statics.checkAccount = function(identifier){
    var self = this;
    this.findOne({ 'identifier' : identifier }, function(err, account){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Checking account:" + account)
        if(account) {
            console.log("user already in db")
            return true
        } else {
            console.log("Creating new user account")
            self.create({
                name : 'username',
                identifier: identifier
            }, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                // if (err) return done(err);
                return false
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: im retarded. after watching so long at this i forgot about it :) thank you!